# Group by date and another field

Tags: python, datetime, group-by

I think I am missing the obvious but I can't seem to group my data using the group by function. To clarify I have a station `ID` and the `date` with the other columns being status `Id`, `bikes` available and docks available. I want to group my data by the `date` and station `ID` with the bikes available and docks available calculated as the mean but it doesn't seem to work.

My code is as follows:

```
Final_Df=df.groupby([df['date'].dt.date],df['station_id']).mean()
```

The type error shows 'Series objects are not mutable, this they cannot be hashed.

I am new to python - any help?

Tried replacing `df['station_id']` with just `station_id` but to no avail. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `groupby` argument should be a single list `[df['date'].dt.date ,df['station_id']]` (note the closing bracket to the right of `['station_id']`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date_Time': pd.date_range('10/1/2001 10:00:00', periods=3, freq='10H'),
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'station_id':[1, 1, 2]})
                   
df.groupby([df['Date_Time'].dt.date, df['station_id']]).mean()
```

results in

```
                         B
Date_Time  station_id     
2001-10-01 1           4.5
2001-10-02 2           6.0
```